# Decompiled .class file, bytecode version46.0(Java 1.3 or older) Download sources/choose cources

Tags: java, android-studio, runtime-error, json-simple

I'm importing a project I wrote on a different machine and I get this error message. The project uses the json.simple package and it is when I'm viewing its sources files that I get this error. I have the option to choose source files from where I can select the json,.simple jar and when I do I get asked "Studio cannot determine what kind of files the chosen items contain. Do you want to attach them as 'Sources'?" Selecting yes doesn't seem to fix anything.

The project as a whole is not working. In stead of my interface I get a blank screen. The code before my calling of json functions seems to be executing but not the json functions or anything after. Yet I don't get any error messages in the logcat.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that works for my question. I've tested all this code and it worked on another PC I can even pull up bits of my code and if I put them before the calling of the json methods they work. I think something is obviously wrong with the json library and how it's implemented. At any rate I do get this error message  at the top of the window where Android Studio also warns you if you need to sync the project. If that gets solved I think all the code will work as well. So it's not that I need help with rewriting the code rather help with using Android Studio.

Comment: Thing is: we can't sit down with you in front of your machine to debug this. So the only chance to *help* you is when you provide us enough information to repro the issue, respectively understand all the relevant parts. Without project structure, library setup, code example ... we can't do that. You are like a guy calling his garage "my car is making strange noises. now tell me how to fix that". Sorry, we can't.